# Excel countdown code error when reaching 0

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have a code that acts as a countdown timer. The reason I'm not using a timer function or simply using the "CountUp" portion to countdown for me is because i'd like it to self adjust (another code could be running causing the calculation time for the other countdown methods to vary and be lengthy). Whenever the code reaches zero it causes an error: Application defined or object defined error.

```
 Sub CountupONE()
 Dim CountDownONE As Date

CountDownONE = Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")

Application.OnTime CountDownONE, "RealcountONE"
End Sub


Sub RealcountONE()
 Dim countONE As Date
 Dim counterONE As Date

 counterONE = Now - Sheets("Sheet1").Range("$A$11").Value
 countONE = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("$B$8").Value - counterONE
 'MsgBox countONE
 Sheets("Sheet1").Range("$C$8") = countONE
 'Sheets("Sheet1").[C8] = TimeValue("12:00:00 AM")

If countONE = TimeValue("12:00:00 AM") Then

Beep
[C11].Value = Now
[C11].NumberFormat = "h:mm:ss AM/PM"
Application.Speech.Speak ("Platen one is done")
Call BeginGraphing

Exit Sub

End If

Call CountupONE
End Sub
```

Comment: which line causes the error?

Comment: Sorry, it erros when it reachs: Sheets("Sheet1").Range("$C$8") = countONE

Comment: What's in B8 and A11? Can you debug.print that?

Comment: Application or object-defined error may indicate the worksheet is protected. Is the worksheet protected?

Comment: It's not that @DavidZemens! I'm getting the same error.

Comment: I think it's do with the way he's subtracting date datatypes that is causing the error.

Comment: Sorry im new to VBA, but when i have the code Debug.Print Sheets("Sheet1").Range("$B$8") nothing comes up other than the original error. B8 and A11 both contain times example for B8: 12:00:20 AM. Example for A11: 1:21:00 PM. Both are formatted to date hh:mm:ss AM/PM.

Comment: The countdown timer also countsdown.. but stops at 0:00:01

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should resolve it:

```
 Sheets("Sheet1").Range("$C$8").Value = TimeValue(CStr(countONE))
```

I am not sure why... It is possible to put a raw `Date` into a cell: `[A1].Value = CDate(Now)`, or even this does not raise an error:

```
countOne = Now()
Range("A1").Value = countOne
```

When the error raises in your case, the value of `countOne` is: March 5, 1785 [and some time value portion].  This has a Long equivalent of -41938.  I don't know why this would cause an error and I would not expect it to.

In any case this method I suggest first coerces `countOne` into a `String` data type, and then pulls out the *time* portion of that value.

Comment: I wish I knew why the original code was causing an error. I certainly would not expect it to :(

Answer (score 1):

`12:00:20 AM` is not `date data type` in your case.

The content of `A11` and `B8` should in the form of `mm/dd/yyyy` for you code to pass. You can add time to that.

Try `02/27/2015` and it will go through!

**Edit**: you can get to work with time like the following line:

```
If Format(countONE, "hh:mm:ss AM/PM") = "12:00:00 AM"
'do here
End if
```

Comment: Nevermind, I think im understanding... I'll mess around with it for a few minutes.